# TensorFlow Keras Use MobileNetV2 Model with Inputs less than 32x32

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mobilenet

I want to use the `MobileNetV2` model without weights with a size less than `32x32`. If I try

```
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(10,10,3),include_top=False,weights=None)
```

gives the error

```
ValueError: Input size must be at least 32x32; got `input_shape=(10, 10, 3)
```

I understand I can't use all the layers because the resolution gets reduced too much in the model, so let's assume I want to use the first 30 layers of the model.

How can I create a model which uses MobileNetV2's first 30 layers and has an input shape of `10x10x3`?  I don't want to manually create the MobileNetV2 model, but I want to use the `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` method to load it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new model from `MobileNet` with the first 30 layers as outputs (i.e. a multiple output model). Here is how:

```
base = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False,weights=None)
features_list = [layer.output for layer in base.layers[:30]]
model = keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=features_list)

len(model.layers) # 30
```

Test

```
img = np.random.random((1, 10, 10, 3)).astype("float32")
model(img)

[<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10, 10, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[[0.7529889 , 0.18826886, 0.9792667 ],
          [0.52218866, 0.36510527, 0.4743469 ],
...
...
```

---

Based on your comment. We can do that. Here is how to do it if you want the model to have a single output which is the output of the 30th layer of the MobileNetV2 model.

```
from keras import layers
input_s = layers.Input((10,10,3))

import tensorflow as tf 
base = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(include_top=False,
                                         weights=None,  
                                         input_tensor = input_s)

from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=base.layers[30].output)
model.summary()
...
...
```

Comment: I don't want a multiple output model.  I think not specifying `input_shape` in `tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` and using `new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=model.layers[:30].output)` works.  However, `new_model` will have input layer with output shape `(None,None,None,3)`.  Is there a way to get this to be `(None,10,10,3)`?

Comment: as far as I can tell from `applications.Mob..`, it seems not feasible to do such. I'm not super sure though. and I also don't see any issues with `(None,None,None,3)`.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I didn't know about the `input_tensor` argument.  That is helpful.  However, as I mentioned I don't want a multiple output model (which your current answer is).  If you get rid of the `features_list` stuff and just use `model = keras.Model(inputs=base.input, outputs=base.layers[30].output)`, then that's the answer I was  looking for.  If you modify your response, I will accept the answer.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Is the given answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it as the right answer or feel free to ask if you encounter any issues. Thanks.